# How can I animate a Dialog to enter from outside the screen?

Tags: qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

> This question is similar to - but no the same as [Moving qml Item out of left side of window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44282347/moving-qml-item-out-of-left-side-of-window), because my question is about Dialogs, instead of Items in general. The difference is explained below.

I have a Qt Dialog which I want to enter the screen from the left.

The first approach I took was setting the dialogs `x` property to `-width` and then adding a `Behavior on x` or a manually triggered `NumberAnimation`.

This approach however failed, because setting negative `x` values is not allowed and the value gets changed to 0 immediately.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44282347/moving-qml-item-out-of-left-side-of-window) provides a solution for this issue, by using anchors and `AnchorChanges` and `transitions` - but only for Items.

However, the `Dialog` type does neither provide states, nor anchors but only coordinates.

So my question stands: *How can I have a QML Dialog animate from the left outside the screen into view?*

Here's a minimal code sample, that demonstrate the `x` property being reset to 0:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Dialog Demo")

    Dialog {
        id: dialog

        width: 200
        height: 200

        x: -width

        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "Ok?"
        }

        standardButtons: Dialog.Ok
        onOpened: x = 100

        Behavior on x { NumberAnimation{ duration: 1000 } }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: dialog.open()
}
```

Comment: Since I think there is a bug, I filed this report: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-67915

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`enter`-transition](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html#enter-prop) that is inherited from `Popup`:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 600

    Dialog {
        id: dialog
        width: 300
        height: 300

        enter: Transition {
            NumberAnimation { properties: "x,y"; from: -300; to: 150 }
        }
    }

    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        onClicked: dialog.open()
    }
}
```

> There seems to be a Bug with the `Dialog`. As soon as the `Dialog` has some content, it fails. I have not discovered all depths of it, but wrapping everything in an `Item` seems to help. Compare for this:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 600

    Dialog {
        id: dialog
        width: 300
        height: 300

        enter: Transition {
            NumberAnimation { properties: "x,y"; from: -300; to: 150; duration: 5000 }
        }

        // HAVE A BUTTON IN THE DIALOG -> POSITIONING FAILS
        Button {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }    
    }

    Button {
        text: 'open'
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        onClicked: dialog.open()
    }
}
```

and

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 600

    Dialog {
        id: dialog
        width: 300
        height: 300

        enter: Transition {
            NumberAnimation { properties: "x,y"; from: -300; to: 150; duration: 5000 }
        }

        Item {  // WRAP IT IN THE ITEM -> WORKS FOR ME
            anchors.fill: parent
            Button {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
        }
    }

    Button {
        text: 'open'
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        onClicked: dialog.open()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I tried your code and it works fine. I have some trouble adding it into my application, but haven't got the time to look into that. I will figure that out later.

Comment: Not works on Qt 5.15.8. the x and y always stays non-negative